# Passing info between views in uinavigation

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I'm implementing a uinavigationcontroller. The first view is a uitableview (imagine the Contacts app) with a list of names.
The second view is the person profile.
So, when I click a person in the uitable, it's suppose to load his profile.

How do I pass the person data to the second view?

In didSelectRowAtIndexPath I do:

```
ContactView * varContactView = [[ContactView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
varContactView.title = [[contactsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] name];
[varContactView initWithPerson:[contactsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
[navigationController pushViewController:varContactView animated:YES];
```

In the interface of ContactView I've got:

```
Person * person;
```

And then:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) Person * person;
-(void) initWithPerson:(Person *)newperson;
```

And in .m:

```
@synthesize person
-(void) initWithPerson:(Person *)newperson{
    person = [[Person alloc] init];
    person = newperson;
}
```

However, when I try to access person in ContactView, it says always EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
[varContactView initWithPerson:[contactsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

you can simply use:

```
varContactView.person = [contactsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

That will make use of `person` property setter and assign the given object as `varContactView`'s data. The default implementation of that setter is (in case of `retain` property):

```
- (void)setPerson:(Person *)newPerson
{
    if (person != newPerson) {
        [person release];
        person = [newPerson retain];
    }
}
```

That's what you're trying to achieve in `-initWithPerson:` method. That method is not needed, as its functionality is covered by `person` property setter. BTW, remember to release `person` property in `-dealloc` method of your view controller:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [person release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

The bad access exception might be caused by something else in your code, though...

Answer (score 0):

In .m file, change the code as given below.

```
-(void) initWithPerson:(Person *)newperson
{
    self.person = newperson;
}
```